# unescaping javascript in rails .rb file / returning js in ruby methods

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following js (in a string literal) returned in one of my plugin's methods.  So when I call the method it puts this in my view.  The problem is on the website, all the `<, ", ', >` etc are escaped into `&lt;, &quot;` and whatnot.  How can I do this? I've tried various ways but none seem to work :/ I think this plugin may be kind of old so this was possible in earlier versions of Rails...

```
%Q{<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#{table_dom_id}').dataTable({
          "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "#{search_label}",
            #{"'sZeroRecords': '#{no_records_message}'," if no_records_message}
            "sProcessing": '#{processing}'
          },
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "iDisplayLength": #{per_page},
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": #{server_side},
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "bStateSave": #{persist_state},
          "bFilter": #{search},
          "bAutoWidth": #{auto_width},
          #{"'aaSorting': [#{sort_by}]," if sort_by}
          #{"'sAjaxSource': '#{ajax_source}'," if ajax_source}
          "aoColumns": [
                #{formatted_columns(columns)}
                    ],
            #{"'fnRowCallback': function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) { #{row_callback} }," if row_callback}
          "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( #{additional_data_string} );
            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    fnCallback(json);
                } );
          }
        })#{append};
    });
    </script>}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets asked pretty often. You need to tell Rails not to escape the string one of two ways:

1. `<%= 'string'.html_safe %>`
2. `<%= raw 'string' %>`

The first is preferred in most cases since it's more flexible. You can, for instance, mark the string as HTML-Safe when it is defined, then if something modifies it it'll automatically be marked as unsafe. This is good to avoid accidentally opening yourself up to an exploit.

**However**, it would be a better idea to move that code into a view of some sort. You should avoid having output in your methods. In the case of helpers, limited output code is best (usually just snippets).

Comment: thanks so much! yeah, ideally it would be elsewhere but I'm trying to change the plugin as little as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically escapes html to prevent from XSS attacks. You've got two options:

```
# Provided that my_escaped_string is what you want to display
<%= my_escaped_string.html_safe %>
<%= raw my_escaped_string %>
```

You can also use `html_safe` in any method as well.

Comment: thank you! sorry have to give my vote to the guy seconds before :(